# Popup warning Message comes while Clicking on Custom Link in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning-experience, custom-link

When a user clicks on a custom link exist in Opportunity path in SalesForce Lightning in IE or Edge but not in Chrome, it is opening in a new tab but on Existing SalesForce page a warning Popup comes, it says:-

> Navigate to this page?
>
> We'd like to open the Salesforce page https://google.com... in a new
>   tab. Because of your browser settings, we need your permission first.

I tried searching the reason behind it and all i got is an idea related to some other warning but does not helped me:-

[Disable popup message on navigating outside Salesforce](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E57qQAC)

Why this is happening?

Comment: This might be a restriction in the browser settings. Under site permissions for the applicable domain URL, give the "Allow" permission to Pop-ups and redirects and try again.

Comment: Yes, even i tried will all the settings, but no luck :(