# Stop SF Lightning from trying to open up Set Up Content in a new tab

Tags: lightning-experience, bug, safari

When I am in Set Up and attempt to open something, like User Profiles for example, I always get this modal that asks `We'd like to open the Salesforce page ... in a new tab` and then when you allow it, it opens up the view in a new tab where no JS works, causing the page to be useless.

Is there a way to fix this issue? It seems to only happen in Safari, but its a pretty ridiculous issue to even exist.

Comment: Are you on Safari 11.x+? Do you see any errors in the Web Inspector? Are you running plugins? As far as I can tell, it shouldn't be doing this unless there's an underlying error somewhere. Any additional details you can provide would be appreciated.

Comment: I am running Safari 12.1 and no extensions. I do get two 404 errors when these routes are attempting to load:

`/javascript/1553688346000/ui-sfdc-javascript-impl/source/SfdcCore.js.map` and `/javascript/1553688290000/sfdc/source/AuraAlohaFrameNavigator.js.map`

Comment: The map files are not necessary for normal operation. Thanks for the additional information. You most likely will want to report a bug directly to salesforce by opening a case. I haven't seen any other instances of this yet, and I don't have a computer to run Safari on, but between Support and perhaps someone here that knows more, hopefully you'll get an answer.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246169/popup-warning-message-comes-while-clicking-on-custom-link-in-lightning-experienc

Comment: This happens to me but only in Safari, not Chrome or Edge. Does anyone have a fix?

Answer (score 0):

May want to review your browser's plugins/extensions and add salesforce.com as an allowed site. Specifically Firefox's built in Content Blocking was forcing the pages into a new browser tab; once I disabled it, it starting working as expected.